# Let $ n \geq 3 $. By factorising $ n $ or $n + 1 $ (as appropriate), show that $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}] $ is not a UFD

Tags: ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $ n \geq 3 $. By factorising $ n $ or $n + 1 $ (as appropriate), show that $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}] $ is not a UFD.

My thoughts so far:

Define $ N(a + b \sqrt{-n}) = a^2 + n b^2 $.

Suppose $ n $ is odd. Then $ n + 1 $ is even, say $ n + 1 = 2k $. Now $ N(2) = 4 $, and the norm of an element in this ring can never be 2, so we have that 2 is irreducible. Now note that $ 1 + n = (1 + \sqrt{-n})(1 - \sqrt{-n}) $. Is $ 1 + \sqrt{-n} $ irreducible? Well, if $ 1 + \sqrt{-n} = z_1 z_2 $, then $ N(z_1)N(z_2) = 1 + n $. So $ N(z_i) \leq \frac{n+1}{2} < n $. But this means both $ z_i$ must be purely real, which clearly can't be the case. Similarly, $ 1 - \sqrt{-n} $ is irreducible. Neither of these factors are equal to 2, and so 2 appears in one factorisation but not another. Hence for $ n $ odd, we don't have a UFD.

What about $n$ even? How can I factorise $ n $ other than as $ 2k $ for some $k $?

Thanks

EDIT: I overlooked $ n = \sqrt{-n} ( -\sqrt{n}) $!

Comment: But this is not always true, although in most cases it is.

Comment: Can you give me a counterexample?

Comment: @Adrian, perhaps you are thinking of $n$ such that the ring of integers in ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-n})$ is a UFD? But if those $n$ are $3$ mod $4$, then the ring of integers is not ${\bf Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$.

Comment: @user938272: In your edit, you mean $n=-\sqrt{-n}\sqrt{-n}$. Note that $\sqrt{n}\notin\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$.

Comment: @Gerry: And if $n$ is not square free, you also get other things. If $n=4$,then $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-4}]$ is not the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-4}) = \mathbb{Q}(i)$, either.

Comment: @Gerry Yes, you're absolutely right. I was thinking of the rings of integers of the imaginary quadratic fields of class number 1. I also thought about what you said that in the case in which $-n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ then $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$ is not the full ring of integers. But I was just leaving my office and didn't have a chance to look at them (I don't remember all of them =P) and now that I look what they are I realize that all of them have $-n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. My bad for leaving such a comment when I don't have time to actually look things up. But at least I learned something new =)

Answer (score 2):

*This CW answer intends to remove the question from the unanswered queue*

---

Your thoughts are correct and if you correct your edit according to [this comment by Arturo Magidin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37513/let-n-geq-3-by-factorising-n-or-n-1-as-appropriate-show-that#comment82292_37513) you will find a similar argument for even $n$.